# Spotlight indexing of back up drive

Tags: time-machine, spotlight

I've seen some posts about whether you can stop spotlight constantly indexing your time machine backup drive. It seems you can't have it attached to your computer and not have it indexed.

I have been getting around the problem by demounting my backup drive and then remounting it when I want to back up.

I wonder if any anyone has a script that would mount, backup and unmount a backup drive every 6 hours or so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To not have Spotlight index your Time Machine hard drive while it's powered and attached to your Mac, add Time Machine backup drive (by clicking on the + button at the Privacy tab of the Spotlight system preference. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This link provides a solution to backing up using Time Machine at customized intervals or events:
http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/

You can disable Time Machine the system preferences when using this tool.

[image]
[image]